# angular WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hey I'm trying to display a search bar in a modal by writing the html in the modal body like so:

```
onClick() {
      const dialogRef = this.modal.alert()
        .size('lg')
        .showClose(true)
        .title('A simple Alert style modal window')
        .body(`
          <div class="card container-fluid col-xs-10">
          <div class="card-block">
              <div class="form-group row">
                  <div class="col-5">
                      <ng2-completer class="completer-limit"
                                     [(ngModel)]="searchStr"
                                     [datasource]="dataService"
                                     [minSearchLength]="0"
                                     [inputClass]="'form-control'"
                                     [placeholder]="'Enter the class you would like to add'"
                                     [matchClass]="'match'"
                                     [autofocus]="true"
                                     [textSearching]="false">
                      </ng2-completer>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>`)
        .open();
    }
```

The html in the .body is trying to reference data in the same .ts file as the onClick function. For reference running this html in the corresponding html document works great (not in a modal). Also adding generic html in the modal works fine (simple text). However when I add this code the search bar is not rendered and in the developer console it says: WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss). Anyone have any idea what is going on? Sorry if this question is tough since I'm using packages. They are ng2-completer for the search bar and ngx-modialog for the modal. I think the issue may be fundamental and not related to the packages however which is why I'm asking on stackoverflow. Is the problem that the html in the modal body cannot reference the .ts file this onClick function is in since the template is pointing to a seperate html file or should I still be able to reference objects in the .ts file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing HTML in a string to the `modal.alert().body()` function

So Angular doesn't trust it. It is potentially a source of code injection, and is therefore sanitised. You need to find another way - does your modal accept a template or component as a parameter, if so, that will be the way to do it.

Comment: I thought it was something like that. I tried using ng-template and passing it as .body(myTemplate) (myTemplate having been passed as a parameter to onClick from the html) but it just displayed [Object object]. I believe it may accept a component. I need to reference data in this component however and I would prefer having the search bar in this component... Maybe I'm passing the template incorrectly. Let me know please.

Comment: I don't know which modal you are using, and I believe I answered your question, and the next bit of research is yours to do